# How to access the instance of another component?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm not necessarily talking about a child component, so `ViewChild` isn't an option.

Is it possible to inject any component into another component? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617293/angular2-inject-components-into-other-components), but it's outdated.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is a service to manage an Observable/Subject that both components can access.

See this answer for an implementation example
[Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924#35568924)

And for reference, here is a list of ways to currently interact between different components:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I do not wish to only communicate between components, I need to obtain a reference to the component instance itself.

Comment: It's not possible as far as I know. You need to use ViewChild or ViewChildren if you want to reference the object. But I don't see what you can't achieve by storing state in a service?